# Hover effect close in 3sec even if cusor is on it

Tags: css

I have written the following CSS and put it `element:after` to delay the hover effect to close.

```
transition: .50s all;   
transition-delay: 3s;
```

Now I want the hover effect will be close after 3 even if the cursor is on the element.

In CSS is there any way to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more clearly? "Now I want the hover effect will be close after 3 even if the cursor is on the element." is hard to make sense of. You want the hover effect to go away after another 3 seconds? I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, can you provide a bit more detail, please? A full sample of what you have at the moment would help.

Comment: Please include the html that you're wanting the css to take effect on and the actual css rule. Describe what the element's style should tell the user and what specific css properties you have been planning to use.

Comment: Thank you @ajmajmajma for replying. Actually, now the hover effect getting close after 3 sec if I move the cursor from the element. But I stay the cursor in it then it is not closing after 3 sec.

Comment: Can you recreate a minimalistic example of the issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a keyframe animation instead, whilst setting the iteration count to 1:

**note**

Prefixing will be required.

**Demo**

```css
div {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: tomato;
}
div:hover{
  -webkit-animation: 3s linear hoverit;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation: 3s linear hoverit;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation: 3s linear hoverit;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hoverit{
  0%{background:tomato;}
  10%{background:blue;}
  90%{background:blue;}
  100%{background:tomato;}
  }
@-moz-keyframes hoverit{
  0%{background:tomato;}
  10%{background:blue;}
  90%{background:blue;}
  100%{background:tomato;}
  }
@keyframes hoverit{
  0%{background:tomato;}
  10%{background:blue;}
  90%{background:blue;}
  100%{background:tomato;}
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Arif: glad i could help. If there's any issues give me a shout :)

Comment: surely I will knock you.

Answer (score 1):

use animation instead of transition

```
@keyframes doMagic {
    0% {
       // initial styles
    }
    100% {
       // hover styles
    }
}

.selector {
   animatiom: doMagic 3s ease forwards;
   animation-delay: 3s; // not sure if u need it
}
```

using the keyword `forwards` you tell the animation to stay in its finished state

read more on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

if you DONT put that . the animation will play to 100% then go to initial state

Comment: I agree that OP can get his wanted effect with animations, by "reverting" the animation near the end. As I understand it, he does actually want the animation to go back to its initial state at the end.